# Excel Lookup formula based on 2 dependent lists or variables

Tags: microsoft-excel

So im trying to create a table that uses two dependent lists, which i have done, however I need a third cell to show a string of text that is specific to the first two selections in my list. Example. I have several category a, b, c topics to choose. From there each topic has several sub topics, then depending on the sub topic, I need cell C4 to display a specific message for that sub topic. What formula can I use for the message field?

Comment: It would be great if you can copy and paste in a screenshot of your input data as well as a picture of out desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a table of these text messages some where in another sheet like so:

```
a    a.1    Message1
a    a.2    Message2
b    b.1    Message3
b    b.2    Message4
b    b.3    Message5
```

Then in your main sheet, you would have

```
b    b.1    *lookup formula here*
```

where the formula is something like

```
=VLOOKUP("b.1",INDEX(sheet1!B1:sheet1!B100, MATCH("b",sheet1!A1:sheet1!A100,0)):sheet1!C100,2,FALSE)
```

where `MATCH("b",sheet1!A1:sheet1!A100,0)` returns the row number of the first occurrence of "b", which then gets converted to a range reference using index `INDEX(sheet1!B1:sheet1!B100, *row where 'b' occurs*,0)):sheet1!C100`. This ranges thus starts with topic "b"'s subtopics and runs to the end of the data range in C. This range is then used with VLOOKUP to find the first occurrence of the subtopic "b.1" and return the message in column two of this range (i.e. column C).

Answer (score 0):

Also, if the topics are few or repeat in subtopics, you can hardcode the messages using the choose function. First convert the topic and subtopic into numbers (i.e. the order they appear in the lists).

```
=MATCH("b",A1:A100,0)
=MATCH("b.1",B1:B100,0)
```

Now use those numbers as an index into CHOOSE

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH("b",A1:A100,0),"topic A msg","topic B msg","topic C msg")
```

and

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH("b.1",B1:B100,0),"subtopic 1 msg","subtopic 2 msg","subtopic 3 msg")
```

You can then combine those into a single cell with the & operator i.e. `=CHOOSE(...) & ": " & CHOOSE(...)`